# Page Viewer Web Part is not working when I am trying to access other site on my SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-server

I am working on SharePoint server 2013 web application and I added a Page viewer Web part.

Trying you access the Facebook link it gives the error **(To help protect the security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame)**

[image]

Open the content on on new window, it open the site, but I need the feeds should come on SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

### To allow or disallow iFrames for a site collection:

1. Browse to the root site of your site collection.
2. Click **Settings** > **Site Settings** > **Site Collection Administration** > **HTML Field Security**.
3. Select one of the following options:

   - **Do not permit contributors to insert iframes from external domains
     into pages on this site** to disallow the use of iFrames for all sites
     in the site collection.
   - **Permit contributors to insert iframes from any external domain into
     pages on this site** to allow the use of iFrames for all sites in the
     site collection and to allow data from any external website to be
     displayed in the iFrame. For security reasons, we do not recommend
     this option.
   - **Permit contributors to insert iframes from the following list of
     external domains into pages on this site** to add a web domain to a
     list of domains whose content can be displayed in iframes in the site
     collection. To remove a website from the list, select it, and then
     click Remove.

   [image]
4. Click **OK**.

**Reference:**

- https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Allow-or-disallow-iframes-for-a-site-collection-C0A622C3-5E1B-4EE5-9764-BC8BC63AE8E0?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US
- https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Display-a-Web-page-on-a-SharePoint-page-by-adding-the-Page-Viewer-Web-Part-7f61feec-9b3d-4805-a960-07636ba59527

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have gone through this link but the problem is  I don't have the rights to access Site Collection Administration. Is there any other way. The other solutions I have came across is if we add the site as a trusted site then also it can work, but over here also I don't have rights

Comment: No. If you don't have access to Site Collection Administration then you can not do it because it's the security that Microsoft is maintaining.

Comment: Any other option where I can call the other site group information as a news feed

Comment: Dikesh Gandhi: I had try the solutions, which you have given still its not working, can you please me with any other option.

Comment: Tried to add facebook page as iframe in simple html file and check if it's working or not. If not then facebook is protecting its page from being used in iframe.